# React formik with React-select Convert multiple select array to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, formik, react-select

Hi I am using react formik and react-select package I create form create and update in component. I want to create an multiple Select values are send to string But now going as array. On update also want to Bind as string Is it possible.

Please Help us Thanks for Help

code Sandbox Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselect-formik-3eqxp?file=/src/RegisterForm.js

Comment: code sandbox link does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if you want something else, but this is what I understand. You want `developer,engineer` to be sent to the API. Change you onSubmit like this and you will get the jobs the way you want.

```
 const onSubmit = (values) => {
    const jobs = [];
    values.job.map((ele) => jobs.push(ele.value));
    console.log("text => ", jobs.toString());
  };
```